# Edits by Anonymous user and approved by Community Bot

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

This is **again** regarding [this post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/180402/why-does-balancing-the-reduction-of-dichromatevi-to-chromiumiii-require-four). If I see the history, there are many suggested edits:[image]

I can see there is involvement of a moderator who rolled back the edit. Even after rollback, multiple edits happen ([can confirm who did it](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/whats-the-point-of-users-commenting-the-url-of-the-question-itself-in-the-comme)) and it were either rejected or approved. As of writing this post, there is a proposed edit by an anonymous user:
[image]

Previous edits seems to be harmless but now this is turning out to be vandalism even though the edits are minute. Can some mods check on this and take strong action (like locking)?

Moreover, we need to look at the  bigger picture. How come an anonymous user can edit a post and get it approved? Even if the edits are towards improving the quality of the post, the user proposing must have an account on the site to hold some credibility. Also, the system need to detect automatically such users (or sockpuppet accounts) and ban them from editing any posts (if it sees multiple edits within a short frame of time).

Comment: The CMs have been contacted regarding these issues.

Comment: You know it's likely same thing? https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5399/whats-the-point-of-users-commenting-the-url-of-the-question-itself-in-the-comme

Comment: BTW, it looks like making a lot of fuss because of a noob, who doesn't know what he's doing. How is it we don't even have real vandalism? ;p

Comment: @Mithoron there is a bigger picture to look at.

Comment: One certainly can make suggested edits as a guest, that's nothing new. It's not really community that accepts, but OP - the bot is just a proxy for the ones without enough rep. to do it single-handedly.

Comment: @Mithoron should we not do smtg about this?

Comment: @HarikrishnanM About what? How site works, or that people don't know its mechanisms? The first we can't do much, but these posts here are somewhat informative, helping with the second ;)

Comment: If the bot is behaving like the President in India, like a figurehead to stamp the recommendations of the Parliament (the anonymous  user), this might reduce post quality.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM Did I say smtg unclear? OP accepts edits. Similarly OP can accept a post being a duplicate and Community dupehammers it for him.

Comment: Ok, but I never got any notification to accept any edit that comes to my posts....

Comment: @HarikrishnanM For ex. [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/166628) you made a suggested edit reviewed by OP. It's possible nobody made a suggested edit on any of your posts, or you didn't notice and it was reviewed by +2k users.

Comment: Okay, I got it!