Targeted troll comments
I have been receiving some troll comments in some of my older posts. Now, I have been busy with work stuff, so couldn't care less about this. So, I flagged these comments and moved on. Today I see for the same posts, there are multiple spam comments:

The user id seems to be different (and deleted) but it might be the action of a single user exploiting the loophole in the system. Can't the system detects such troll comments automatically and delete them? Because if I flag them today, they will again spawn tomorrow.

Update: I wish I have taken some backup or screenshots before flagging, but oh well! As per request, sharing the posts where I received spam comments:

Is Tollen's test safe? (the above screenshot is from this post)
Contact explosion of nitrogen triiodide
Disposal of Silver Halides dissolved in Ammonium Hydroxide
Will disodium EDTA effectively destroy Tollens' reagent? (The last comment is a spam - DO NOT DELETE IT. It will serve as an evidence)

Those who handled my flags knows what comments I am talking about - guess I am not getting the Nobel prize :/

Update 2 [29th September 2024]:
Yesterday, I received an unnecessary comment:

The question linked is this one: Why does ozone disproportionate on reaction with potassium iodide? where there are more comments:

There were quite a few more but I guess they were deleted by troll itself. I am not active that much lately, so 1. I noticed now only 2. these comments annoyed me.
I am not sure if anyone else is receiving such comments but seems like the troll loves to target me.
.... and harass fellow users.


I'm aware that you are being targeted by the troll. Seems we are unable to close the gaping loophole and stuck cleaning their actions by hand. My guess is there might be a way to undo changes using a script (or bot) but it would involve someone else's time and effort to develop. We can raise this with CMs and see if anything can be done.

Unfortunately the system does not list deleted comments - I believe it used to but that was changed - which leaves me unable to find which posts have been re-spammed without going through all your posts. Flags remain the easiest way for us to be made aware and deal with this.

@BuckThorn Thanks! I have listed the posts where there were spam comments.

How did you note that last comment? It wasn't to one of your posts.

I was tagged in one of the comments earlier. I flagged it. Today, I checked a new comment @BuckThorn

Well, it's most likely your autocomment friend https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/edits-by-anonymous-user-and-approved-by-community-bot

@Mithoron We are not sure about that. There are many issues plaguing the site.

BTW don't worry about deleting the comments provided you retain a link to the post where they appeared (such as you've done here). We can trace the comments easily as long as we know which posts to look at.

A CM was contacted regarding the issue and steps were taken to curb the unwanted behavior. However it is far from guaranteed that this will be the end of the troll's participation.
Mods can protect posts when flags make them aware of disruptive behavior such as junk comments, edits and answers. Protecting raises the required rep level of the participant and can limit trolling (but potentially also reduce participation by non-trolls).

"However it is far from guaranteed that this will be the end of the troll's participation.". Yeah,  that person rose from his slumber: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/184249/17368

Yep. The CMs have been notified.

Did you got any response from CMs? The bot again commented and defaced one of my posts. Wouldn't it be better if you mark it for [status-review]?

This post already went through status-review and was handled by CMs.
